Log-Return Distribution Assumptions in VaR and CVaR Calculation Using Monte Carlo Simulation with the Heston Model
I want to calculate VaR and CVaR using Monte Carlo simulation and by estimating volatility with the Heston model. Do the asset log-returns have to be normally distributed? Because I haven't found any references stating that log-returns must be normally distributed.

VaR calculations often assume that returns are normally distributed - perhaps, the distribution assumption is used to calculate the risk measure analytically for those portfolios which only contains linear instruments. On the other hand, simulations are more time consuming - perhaps the risk measure is calculated through the distribution (realization of each simulation) up to the time horizon - without needs of distribution assumptions.

It’s possible to derive VaR and CVaR without assuming the he returns follow a normal distribution. Key part here is that you you understand your assumptions and apply the model properly.

As others have mentioned you do not need the normal assumption for returns to calculate VaR by simulation or historical data. FYI: VaR calculated using the normal assumption is called "delta normal VaR".
